# Highpass filter applied to noise

Tags: filters, noise, gaussian, highpass-filter

Suppose the input signal is represented as $$y=x+w$$ where $x$ is the signal to be estimated and $w$ is AWGN. I design a high pass filter $H$. What does $$H^{T}Hw$$ represent? Will it be just AWGN but attenuated or will it AWGN completely distorted. We can also assume that $\sigma_w = 0.2$

Comment: $H^\mathrm{T}$ is the adjoint filter and $H^\mathrm{T}Hw$ is simply applying it to the output of the first filter. Multiply the two spectrums of $h$ and its adjoint to see what the combined effect of the two will be.

Comment: It appears that you refering to some literature but you fail to mention what is sigma_w means here. Further Transpose(H).H is a constant (Sum of Squares of filter coefficients). Then Transpose(H).H.w will be a scaled signal.

Comment: $\sigma_w=0.2$ implies the standard deviation of the noise. And btw $H^THw$ is not a scaled signal. Nikita's answer below seems right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula represents noise component of the output signal. AWGN stands for additive white gaussian noise, than after passing through the filter the noise will still be additive and gaussian but NOT white.